# Why is pyrrhotite LESS magnetic the MORE iron it contains?

Tags: material-science, molecules, metals, ferromagnetism

Usually, the more iron the better....

Pyrrhotite is an iron sulfide mineral with the formula Fe(1-x)S (x = 0 to 0.2). It is a nonstoichiometric variant of FeS, the mineral known as troilite. Pyrrhotite is also called magnetic pyrite, because the color is similar to pyrite and it is weakly magnetic. The magnetism decreases as the iron content increases, and troilite is non-magnetic.

Is it because if there is 'too much' iron, the magnetic domains align antiparallel(ly), and the material becomes antiferromagnetic?  Or at least ferromagnetic, rather than ferromagnetic?

Comment: _"ferromagnetic, rather than ferromagnetic"_ — is there a mistake here?

Comment: Can you provide links which substantiate these statements? That may help people explain the apparent contradiction.